# how to write test cases for non crud operations and private method in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The search method is non-crud action and map is a private method, restaurant, dish, location, pictures are models. these models data contains an array. so how I write test case for map method and search method. restaurant and location has HABTM association, and also restaurant and dish has HABTM association, restaurant and pictures have a polymorphic association, and also dish and pictures has a polymorphic association

```
  def search
  map                                                               

   if params[:name]
        @items = Dish.search(params[:name])
   end
   if params[:price]
        @items = Dish.sortby_price(params[:price]).search(params[:name])
    end

   if params[:ratings]
        @items = Dish.sortby_ratings(params[:name])
   end
   if params[:rating]
        @items = Dish.sortby_rating(params[:rating])
    end
   if params[:category]
        @items= Dish.sortby_dietary(params[:category]).search(params[:name])
    end
  if params[:restaurant]
        @restaurants = 
        Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant])
        @items = @restaurants.dishes

     end    

  end

private
def map
    @items = Dish.search(params[:name])
    restaurants = []
    locations = []
    pictures = []

    @items.each do |d|
        @restaurants = d.restaurants
        restaurants.push(@restaurants)
        d.restaurants.each do |r|
            @pictures = r.pictures
            pictures.push(@pictures)
            @locations = r.locations
            locations.push(@locations)
        end 
    end  
    gon.restaurants = restaurants
    gon.locations = locations
    gon.pictures = pictures

    x = []
    @items.each do |d|
        @restaurants = d.restaurants
        d.restaurants.each do |r|
            x.push(r.id)
        end 
    end
    y = []
    x.each do |x|
        r = Restaurant.find(x)
        d = r.dishes.count
        y.push(d)
    end
    gon.dishes_count = y
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people say that there is no need to test private methods. But in a company i'm working for we do test private methods.

For your case I'd recommend to do this:

1. test method `#map` separately from action `#search`. You need to check that `gon, @items, @restaurants, @pictures, @locations` objects got populated correctly.
   You can test private methods by using method `#send`.

Example:

```
describe '#map' do
  subject { controller.send(:map) }

  # you would need to stub params method
  before { allow(controller).to receive(:params).and_return({ name: 'my name' }) }

  it { expect(controller.instance_variable_get(:@items)).to include/not be_blank/... }
end
```

2. Test method #search without actually calling method map.

Example:

```
describe '#search' do

  before { allow(controller).to receive(:map) }

  # you can set different context where you test cases with different parameters
  context 'when params[:name] and params[:ratings] exist' do
    before { get :search, { name: '...', ratings: '...' } }

    it {...}
  end
end
```